# How to return values of two date ranges, from the same date column and value column, in two different columns as a result?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have following data in my table,

```
Table = BillHeader

   Sales column = Sales

   Date column = CreateDate

   Location name = Location
```

Result needed:

| Location | Sum_of_Sale_1 | Sum_of_Sale_2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
|  |  |  |
|  |  |  |

Sum_of_Sale_1 = Sum of Sales up to yesterday for this month.

Sum_of_Sale_2 = Sum of Sales up to same date range as Sum_of_Sale_1 during last month.

For example, if today is 20th of June, Sum_of_Sale_1 = Sum of sales from 1st June to 19th of June

and Sum_of_Sale_2 = Sum of sales from 1st May to 19th of May.

Basically what I need is these two results of different date ranges, which should be selected form the same three columns, should appear next to each other in the result. I want to know how the sales performance was last month's same date range as to this month's date range (up to yesterday for this month).

Thanks!!

---

EDIT - 1

Here is the actual current working code:

```
SET @FDM = DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm, 0, GETDATE()), 0)


SELECT sum ([LAB_TRN_BillHeader].[AmountToBePaid]) as Total_Sale
          ,LAB.dbo.[LAB_TRN_BillHeader].[CollectingCenterCode]
          ,LAB.dbo.[LAB_Comm_MST_CollectingCenter].[Name]
          ,LAB.dbo.[LAB_Comm_MST_Branch].[BranchName]


FROM Lab.dbo.[LAB_TRN_BillHeader]

INNER JOIN LAB.dbo.[LAB_Comm_MST_CollectingCenter] on LAB.dbo.[LAB_TRN_BillHeader].[CollectingCenterCode] = LAB.dbo.[LAB_Comm_MST_CollectingCenter].[CollectingCenterCode]

INNER JOIN LAB.dbo.[LAB_Comm_MST_Branch] on LAB.dbo.[LAB_TRN_BillHeader].[BranchCode] = LAB.dbo.[LAB_Comm_MST_Branch].[BranchCode]

WHERE Date between @FDM and DATEADD(day,0, CAST(GETDATE() AS date)) and {{select_Laboratory}} and LAB.dbo.[LAB_TRN_BillHeader].[IsVoid] = '0' and LAB.dbo.[LAB_TRN_BillHeader].[CollectingCenterCode] in ('URCR022','MRPMC','KUCC','KOCC','EHECC')

GROUP BY LAB.dbo.[LAB_TRN_BillHeader].[CollectingCenterCode], LAB.dbo.[LAB_Comm_MST_CollectingCenter].[Name], LAB.dbo.[LAB_Comm_MST_Branch].[BranchName]
```

Current Result:

|Total_Sale|CollectingCenterCode|Name|BranchName|
|xxx       |xxx                 |x   |xx        |

Required Result:

|Total_Sale|Total_Sale2|CollectingCenterCode|Name|BranchName|
|xxx       |xxx        |xx                  |x   |xx        |

Total_Sale = Sale of current month up to yesterday

Total_Sale2 = Sale of Last month up to current month's yesterday's date.

-- MSSQL Version - 2014

-- <Create_Date> is a time stamp in the table in <Create_Date> column. The date/time is obtained from that timestamp. Each transaction is saved with a respective timestamp at it's time of occurrence.

-- {{select_Laboratory}} is a field filter alias in Metabase (this code was copied from a Metabase dashboard). The actual code is LAB.dbo.[LAB_TRN_BillHeader].[BranchCode] = '001'

Comment: Actual sample data and expected results would help us immensely

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are different ways of doing the calculations and I don't know if this logic will seem more straightforward or as concise. Also you might not be able to use variables. Lastly, you didn't specify which version you're running.

Although you can incorporate this into an existing query that covers a wider range of dates, here is a stand-alone option that should restrict the execution to a narrower range of dates. The `case` logic, as written, does assume that rows have already been filtered so the only thing left to determine is whether the sale comes from current month or prior month.

```
select Location,
    sum(case when month(CreateDate) <> month(getdate()) then Sales end) as Sales1,
    sum(case when month(CreateDate)  = month(getdate()) then Sales end) as Sales2
from BillHeader
where
    -- go back enough days to guarantee covering last two months
    -- this may be able to utilize an index
    SalesDate between dateadd(day, -30 - day(getdate()), cast(getdate() as date))
                  and getdate()
    -- now eliminate extra dates that are not relevant
    and month(getdate()) - month(CreateDate) in (0, 1, -11) /* year might roll over */
    and   day(getdate()) >   day(CreateDate)
group by Location;
```

For a YOY comparison over the same calendar month:

```
select Location,
    sum(case when year(CreateDate) <> year(getdate()) then Sales end) as Sales1,
    sum(case when year(CreateDate)  = year(getdate()) then Sales end) as Sales2
from BillHeader
where
    -- go back enough days to guarantee covering last 13 months
    -- (or rewind as 396 days via parallel logic from earlier)
    SalesDate between
        dateadd(year, -1, dateadd(day, 1 - day(getdate()), cast(getdate() as date)))
        and getdate()
    and month(getdate()) = month(CreateDate)
    and   day(getdate()) >   day(CreateDate)
group by Location;
```

This might be better done as a union with two different date ranges combined together:

```
-- ...
where       
    SalesDate between
        dateadd(year, -1, dateadd(day, 1 - day(getdate()), cast(getdate() as date)))
        and dateadd(year, -1, getdate())
-- ... union all ...
where
    SalesDate between
        dateadd(day, 1 - day(getdate()), cast(getdate() as date))
        and getdate()
-- ...
```

Comment: Hi, how can I get the same in, without last month on this date, to last year, same as this month, up to yesterday? Eg; 28th of jan 2022 and 28th of jan 2023. Thanks!

Comment: @IT_Boy Change `-30` to `-396` and the second line of the filter to `month(getdate()) = month(CreateDate)` A union of two ranges might perform better though if it's slow.

Comment: Hi Thanks! However when <month(getdate()) - month(CreateDate) in (0, 1, -11)> is converted to <month(getdate()) = month(CreateDate) in (0, 1, -11)> is done, it returns error <Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'in'.>. If i change the second line < and   day(getdate()) >   day(CreateDate)> is changed to <month(getdate()) = month(CreateDate)> results are incorrect.

Comment: @IT_Boy You're replacing the whole line. The `in` now an equality for the same month number. The day portion doesn't change.

Comment: @IT_Boy You're replacing the whole line. The `in` becomes an equality for the matching month number in the year before. The day portion doesn't change.

Comment: The `case` expressions will also need to compare years rather than months two pivot the output into two separate columns.

Answer (score 1):

You could use conditional aggregation with the following date functions:

`DATEADD(Day, 1, EOMONTH(GETDATE(), -1))` gets the first date of the current month, i.e. current month is Jan-2023 it will return '2023-01-01'.

`CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)` gets today's date.

`DATEADD(Day, 1, EOMONTH(GETDATE(), -2))` gets the first date of the previous month, i.e. current month is Jan-2023 it will return '2022-12-01'.

`DATEADD(Month, -1, CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)` gets the date of the day one-month pre today's date.

```
SELECT Location, 
  SUM(CASE 
       WHEN CreateDate >= DATEADD(Day, 1, EOMONTH(GETDATE(), -1)) AND 
            CreateDate < CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) 
       THEN Sales END) Sum_of_Sale_1,
  SUM(CASE 
       WHEN CreateDate >= DATEADD(Day, 1 ,EOMONTH(GETDATE(), -2)) AND 
            CreateDate < DATEADD(Month, -1, CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)) 
       THEN Sales END) Sum_of_Sale_2
FROM BillHeader
GROUP BY Location
```

[See demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/h1GI2yHF)

Comment: What if CreateDate has time portion? I think you should correct your ranges.

Comment: @CetinBasoz, according to the OP's posted query the CreateDate has **no** time portion.

Comment: No, OP doesn't say that anywhere and a sales is likely have a time portion. There is very little possibility it wouldn't in a real world application. He says 'Date Column = CreateDate', if you read previous and next lines, that 'Date' is not meant to be a data type.

Comment: @CetinBasoz, thank you for your feedback, I updated the date ranges according to your suggestion.  Actually, I tried to avoid using extra DATEADD function, but you are right, mostly, sales are stored with time!

Comment: Great, I upvoted :) I would create variables for those function results and use them in the query for performance reasons and also for readability. Just a suggestion. Also, for ranges like this upper bound should be exclusive for preciseness (>= and <).

Comment: @CetinBasoz, for the upper bound it was getdate() -1 so I used <=, but using <getdate() will be cheaper , thank you again:)

Comment: Create_Date is a time stamp in the database. The date is taken from that timestamp. Each transaction is saved with a respective timestamp. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Considering a sales CreateDate is likely of type Datetime or Datetime2, a safe approach would be:

```
DECLARE @yesterday DATE = GETDATE();
DECLARE @lastMonth DATE = DATEADD(MONTH, -1, @yesterday);
DECLARE @firstDayOfThisMonth DATE = DATEADD(DAY, 1 - DAY(@yesterday), @yesterday);
DECLARE @firstDayOfLastMonth DATE = DATEADD(DAY, 1 - DAY(@lastMonth), @lastMonth);

SELECT @yesterday,
       @firstDayOfThisMonth,
       @lastMonth,
       @firstDayOfLastMonth;

SELECT [locationId],
       SUM(   CASE
                  WHEN CreateDate >= @firstDayOfThisMonth
                       AND CreateDate < @yesterday THEN
                      AmountToBePaid
              END
          ) AS Sum_of_Sale_1,
       SUM(   CASE
                  WHEN CreateDate >= @firstDayOfLastMonth
                       AND CreateDate < @lastMonth THEN
                      AmountToBePaid
              END
          ) AS Sum_of_Sale_2
FROM BillHeader
GROUP BY [locationId];
```

EDIT: Note that in dates like March 31,30 previous month's end date could be Feb 28, 29.